# How to use predict with stored e(b) from old regression

Tags: regression, stata, predict

I know that one can get predicted values as follows:

```
reg y x1 x2 x3
predict pred_values
```

Let's say that I run a regression and store the values:

```
reg y x1 x2
matrix stored_b = e(b)
```

And then I run another regression (doesn't matter what).

Is it possible to use the `predict` command using `stored_b` instead of the current `e(b)`?

(Of course, I could generate the predicted values by manually computing them based on `stored_b`, but this could get tedious if there are many coefficients.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to create a `matrix`. Stata has commands that facilitate the task. Try `estimates store` and `estimates restore`. An example:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto

// initial regression/predictions
regress price weight
estimates store myest
predict double resid, residuals

// second regression/prediction
regress price mpg
predict double residdiff, residuals

// backup and predict from initial regression results
estimates restore myest
predict double resid2, residuals

// should pass
assert resid == resid2

// should fail
assert resid == residdiff
```